# Declaring complex object in isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I create a `dateRangePicker` directive that I declare like this:

```
<date-range-picker start="schedule.start" end="schedule.end"></date-range-picker>
```

My directive is declared as the following:

```
.directive("dateRangePicker", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^form',
            scope: {
                    start: '=',
                    end: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'dateRangePicker.tpl.html',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
```

The issue is that my template: `dateRangePicker.tpl.html` initializes a child scope (the angular-ui's DatePicker component does it through its corresponding controller), so any attempt to write values to `scope.start` or `scope.end` would not affect the directive scope.

I would like to declare my isolated scope, so that the conflict won't occur:
`scope.schedule.start` and `scope.schedule.end`.

I tried to do this:

```
return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^form',
            scope: {
                schedule: {
                    start: '=start',
                    end: '=end'
                }
            }
```

But this error occurs:
`Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'definition.match(LOCAL_REGEXP)')`

Is there a way to achieve it using isolated scope?

I just don't want to have to propagate the scopes through `scope:false` (that works, I tested it) in order to keep a good encapsulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass complex object to scope but not using the syntax you have used. Your parent scope should have schedule object and then in html you can do

```
<date-range-picker schedule="schedule"></date-range-picker>
```

Now you can use it in isolated scope using the familiar syntax

```
scope :{
     schedule:'='
}
```